# Overload action method but different route template(with controller name and without controller name) in .net core 5 MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-routing

I have 2 action method and 1 view. I want  send post request but with controller name after submit on the view. But open page without controller name.

Controller

```
public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("/CreateProduct")]
        public IActionResult CreateProduct()
        {
            Product product = new Product()
            {
                Price = new Price()
            };
            return View(product);
        }
        [HttpPost()]
        public IActionResult CreateProduct(Product product)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

and Actoin

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@model MvcDemo.Models.Product

<form asp-controller="Product" asp-action="CreateProduct" method="post">
    <input type="text" asp-for="Name" placeholder="Product Name"/> <br/>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity"/> <br/>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Price.SimplePrice" placeholder="Price"/> <br/>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Price.DiscountPrice" placeholder="Discount Price"/> <br/>


    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to open Page host/CreateProduct but send post request host/product/CreateProduct after submit.

But not working.

**Http Error 405. This page isn’t working**

Submit button send post request host/CreateProduct. I know the solution to the problem [HttpPost("/CreateProduct")].

But I'm interested in why it doesn't work.

Startup route configuration

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
```

Comment: If you still struggling with the issue you could have a look on [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) Because your `route attribute` has not implemented accordingly

Answer (score 0):

when attribute routing starts from "/" it means that the route starts from root. If you want to start from controller

```
        [HttpPost("/product/CreateProduct")]
        public IActionResult CreateProduct()
```

or add attribute to the controller

```
 [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ProductController : Controller
```

if you want everything working the way you want , you have to map controller route this way . In this case you will not need an attribute routing at all

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

Comment: Yes this is solution but I'm interested in why such overload doesn't work in tag-helpers? Because deleting asp-action and asp-controller and write html `action = '/Product/CreateProduct'` is work if we do not write `[HttpPost("/product/CreateProduct")]` in action.

Comment: @AlizamanHabibli Because there are rules and everything is working properly according the rules. If you don't like these rules you can send an email  to a Microsoft team

Comment: Change question. What is reason wrong redirect asp-controller and asp-action?

Comment: @AlizamanHabibli What is the difference for you? The most important thing is that you can always finc a way to accomplish your task.